# C++ executable builder

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, builder

I'm looking to create an application (preferably C++) that would let me compile an executable with small modifications in the source code (These options would be presented to the user in a console window) such as string data modifications. An example would be I run the application A which prompts me for a string value and I enter Y and then application B is created with a string value that would of been modified to Y.

The reason behind this that I need to produce files through a builder that can be easily distributed without configuration files and such.

I'm just wondering, how can I do it?

Comment: Can you assure a C++ compiler is available on the user's system?  Perhaps you could explain the higher level problem rather than the lower level approach you think you need to use to solve it.

Comment: Are you asking to use a string (or several) of C++ code? I've seen this in data analysis when you have several variables and my be interested in the ratio or some other derived quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you don't need such an application. Use configuration files, data files or anything else to make sure your actual program can adapt without recompiling, but with changing its input data.

Example: application A prompts you for string value, you enter Y, it saves Y to a config file and then launches application B which reads that Y from the config file.

The only case I could imagine when you would actually want to do what you describe, is when a user would supply source/machine code you'll need to execute. But then again, that's why we have embedded scripting langauges and conception of plugins.

Comment: Thanks for your input, however I need to distribute the output file without any config files and such.

Comment: @user1661022 then create the config file after the first run. But I agree with DavidO explain what you want to achive with that and we might be able to help you in a different way. I can only think of one or two reasons for doing this and one of them is not legal.

Comment: 1. Windows executables have "resource section". It's format is well documented, and you may rather quickly made custom resource editor, specially tailored to your application; 2. WinRAR's self-extracting archives can be configured to automatically launch one of the unpacked files. So, your application may unpack itself in a temporary folder, and delete itself upon exiting. 3. You may combine gcc and perl/python into one big fuzzy ball of horror, which will mess with the source code and recompile it. Problems with distribution ensue.

Comment: I need to produce a builder that someday can use to produce an application that has string variable to what the user enters.

Comment: This "builder" will provide essentially the same "application", which would differ only in the actual value of one string variable? Then make "application" store that string in its resource section, and put entire "application" into "builder"s resource section. "Builder" will get a string from a user, extract "application" from itself, fix the string variable in "application" and save it to the disk. But I strongly insist you reconsider your "no-configs" policy. INI-files haven't killed a single puppy ever.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is easier said than done for me. Could you give me any guidance on how to go about storing the string in the resource section...I'm having some difficulties reading from the Resource section.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "pseudo" configuration file: you create all data that would be saved to a configuration file and then append that data to your executable. When the created program runs, it can read the data from the executing file.